# Implement sorting function

Tags: matlab, function

I wish to implement a MATLAB function that takes three scalar as inputs and returns a row vector.

The smallest input scalar should be the first element and largest scalar should be the last element of row vector. I can't use the `sort` function.

Below my code but it does not work.

```
function nw = new(s,m,l)

if s >= m || m >= l
    if s == m && m == l
        nw = [s m l]
    else
        s > m && m > l
        nw = [s m l]
        if  s == m && m>l
            nw = [l m s];
        else s > m && m == l
            nw = [l m s];
        end
    end
else s <= m || m <= l
    if s < m && m < l
        nw = [s m l];
    else s == m && m < l
        if s < m && m == l
            nw = [l m s]
        else
            if s > m && s < l
                nw = [l m s]
            end
        end       
end
end
```

Comment: so `new(3,1,4)` should return `[1 3 4]`? why don't you use `sort([3 1 4])`?

Comment: It is always good to give an example of your inputs, expected output, and current output. Please.

Comment: If input is (2,1,3) then output would be (1,2,3).

Comment: I edited the title and question to make it clearer that you wish to implement a sorting function without using the built-in `sort`. Hope this is okay with you!

Comment: Can you use the `min` and `max` function ?

Comment: I can use min and max function

Comment: `else <condition>` is not valid Matlab syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not the most efficient (fastest) way to do it, but it's fun to play with that from time to time.

This function will sort your 3 numbers in a lot less instructions:

```
function nw = new(s,m,l)

v = [s m l ] ; %// group all variable in one array

if all(v == v(1)) %// check just in case they are all the same value
    nw = v ;
else
    [~,ix(1)] = min( v ) ; %// assign the index of the smallest value
    [~,ix(3)] = max( v ) ; %// assign the index of the largest value
    ix(2) = 6 - sum(ix) ;  %// find the middle index by difference (because cumsum([1 2 3]) = 6 )
    nw = v(ix) ;           %// assign the output vector based on indices collected
end
```

Comment: @DumbCoder, no problem. Next time try to define the limits of your problem better in your original question. Also consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem (the green tick mark under the voting buttons). It shows the system that the question has been solved.

Comment: I did not understand the 'all(v == v(1))', could you please explain me a bit? more importantly, why v(1) is there?

Comment: `v==v(1)` compare each element of `v` to the first element (`v(1)`), and it return a vector of Boolean. If all elements are equal, then it return `[1 1 1]` for example. Then `all( ... )` of a vector, return `true` if all the elements are `true`. It's a shortcut of comparing each element together. It's the equivalent of doing `if( v(1)==v(2) & v(1) == v(3) & v(2)==v(3) )`. For 3 values it's not big deal but for very long vectors it's a real good shortcut to know.

Comment: Thank you Hoki for your time. This problem wasted my 17 hours to solve but finally with your code i got the correct result.

Comment: Thank you Hoki for your time. This problem wasted my 17 hours to solve but finally with your code i got the correct result. Okay, when i type v==v(1) it compares the each values of v to the first element of v that is v(1). when i put all(v==v(1)) it does the same as it contains v(1) but what if i type all(v==v). all(v==v) seems logical to me. Can you tell me more why we put all and v(1) in a statement?as v(1) restricts us to only first element of v(1)

Comment: This test is only to make sure **all** values of the vectors are equal. If you do `v==v` this will compare each value element-wise (one by one) and everything will always be true. In your command window, type: `v=[2 3 4]`, then type `v==v` and after that `v==v(1)` ... you will notice the difference in the results.

Comment: Thank You Hoki, I am new on site and this site seems full of so many nice people.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function nw = new(s,m,l)
v = [s m l];
nw = [min(v), median(v), max(v)];
```

Can anyone think of a case where this doesn't work? I can't...

Comment: Tried it with all sorts of input ... can't fault it. Quick and easy! (and I didn't know about the `median` function, thanks.)

Answer (score -1):

When I got you right, you can use sort:

```
function nw = new(s,m,l)
  nw = sort([s,m,l]);
end
```

Comment: Thank you man, but i am instructed not to use sort function. I have to solve that without sort function.

Answer (score -1):

```
function [x,y,z]= sort3(A);
B=size(A);
if B(1,1)==1
a=A(1,1);
b=A(1,2);
c=A(1,3);
elseif B(1,1)==3
C=A'
a=C(1,1);
b=C(1,2);
c=C(1,3);
end
if a>=b && a>=c
 if b>=c
    row = [c b a];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
elseif b<=c
    row = [b c a];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
end
elseif b>=a && b>=c
if a>=c
    row = [c a b];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
elseif a<=c
    row = [a c b];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
end
elseif c>=a && c>=b
if a>=b
    row = [b a c];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
elseif a<=b
    row = [a b c];
    x=row(1,1);
    y=row(1,2);
    z=row(1,3);
    end
end
```